# pandas read_csv does not read column names from header=o if separator is ; (i.e. non-standard separator)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a CSV into pandas and the lines are separated by a ';'. and when I add headher=0 (or header = 'infer') the result is like this:

[image]

Whereas when I tested another file that had the lines separated via ',' then all the column headers are imported correctly.

WHAT IS THE ISSUE?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works fine for me with `'read_csv('...', header='infer', sep=";")`. Show a sample of your file and a code where you read it.

Comment: Thanks for that. We double checked and indeed the issue was about 12 ; in the first row... 
FACEPALM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I Don't know that what's inside in your `csv` file but now after using `pandas.read_csv()` method you can do:-

```
df.columns=df.loc[0]
df.drop(index=0,inplace=True)
df=df.reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
```